# Sessions collection is not set up; waiting until next sessions refresh interval: Replication has not yet been configured

Tags: mongodb, bash, docker, docker-compose, replication

I have a docker-compose.yml file that makes three mongo container which includes three replica sets, my containers build without any problem but setupmongo.sh does not work when my services run correctly. i mean rs.initiate() function does not work on bash file but when i try to run rs.initiate() function with its parameters manually(in docker interactive terminal) it was working correctly my replicas behaves as it should be. As result i need to run rs.initiate() function on bash file

Here my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  mongo1:
    hostname: mongo1
    container_name: mongo1
    image: mongo:4.0.4
    command: mongod --replSet devrs
    volumes:
      - ./mongodb/data1/db:/data/db
      - ./mongodb/data1/configdb:/data/configdb
    networks:
      - mongo-dev-net
    expose:
      - 27017
    ports:
      - 30001:27017
    restart: always

  mongo2:
    hostname: mongo2
    container_name: mongo2
    image: mongo:4.0.4
    command: mongod --replSet devrs
    volumes:
      - ./mongodb/data2/db:/data/db
      - ./mongodb/data2/configdb:/data/configdb
    networks:
      - mongo-dev-net
    expose:
      - 27017
    ports:
      - 30002:27017
    restart: always

  mongo3:
    hostname: mongo3
    container_name: mongo3
    image: mongo:4.0.4
    command: mongod --replSet devrs
    volumes:
      - ./mongodb/data3/db:/data/db
      - ./mongodb/data3/configdb:/data/configdb

    networks:
      - mongo-dev-net
    expose:
      - 27017
    ports:
      - 30003:27017
    restart: always

  mongo-config:
    container_name: mongo-config
    image: alpine
    networks:
      - mongo-dev-net
    depends_on:
      - mongo1
      - mongo2
      - mongo3
    volumes:
      - ./setupmongo.sh:/setupmongo.sh
    entrypoint: ["/setupmongo.sh"]

networks:
  mongo-dev-net:
```

And setupmongo.sh file

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Start"

mongo  <<EOF
rs.config()

rs.initiate(
{
    "_id" : "devrs",
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "host" : "mongo1:27017",
            "priority": 2
        },
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "host" : "mongo2:27017",
            "priority": 0
        },
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "host" : "mongo3:27017",
            "priority": 0
        }
    ]
}
)
EOF
```

Lastly replica set isn't initialized

Comment: He's trying to connect to its own `27017` port and you have nothing running on it. Shouldn't a DB be there, in `mongo-config:27017`?

Comment: When your script runs `mongo`, how does it know where to connect?

Comment: @samthegolden you mean i should remove mongo-config service and add     " entrypoint: ["/setupmongo.sh"] "  mongo services accordingly mongo1, mongo2, mongo3

Comment: I don't know mongo. But probably yes.

Comment: @DavidMaze updated docker-compose.yml file, unfortunately still not working

Answer (score 0):

The ports 30001,30002 and 30003 are `HOST` ports, not `CONTAINER` ports, in the way you configured. The format is `HOST:CONTAINER`. See the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports).

So, you have to connect to 27017 of each container and change the entrypoint accordingly: `mongo1:27010`, `mongo2:27010`, `mongo3:27010`.

And that will work because you already exposed that port in each container.

Comment: i had tried like this  rs.initiate({_id:"devrs",members:[{_id:0,host:"mongo1:27017",priority:2},{_id:1,host:"mongo2:27017",priority:0},{_id:2,host:"mongo3:27017",priority:0}]}); but i did not work